# IDE shortcuts - intelij IDEA to VSC

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellij-idea, key-bindings

In intellij Idea, I could type "psvm" for a main method, and "fori" to get a for loop, and "sout" to get a system println, is there a way to customize intellisense in visual studio code to get the same behavior?

Answer (score 0):

VSCode has many extensions that provide "snippets", shortcuts for code segments like you mentioned. The [C/C++ extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) which you might already have installed provides some for C++, such as `main` for a main method and `for` for a for loop. If you have the extension installed, snippets work exactly like other intellisense suggestions; you can simply type them and then press enter or tab to apply them.

You can also look for other snippet extensions by searching for `@category:"Snippets"` in the extension section.

Comment: Looking back I kind of assumed you were working with C++, I don't really know why. Since you didn't specifically state which language you're working with, you're going to have to look for a snippet extension for that language yourself using the method I mentioned.